# YouTube Player Inside Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

I'm creating an app with tabbed activity and I want to put YouTube player on third tab.

Currently I have this java code :

```
public class FragmentTutorial extends Fragment {

    public FragmentTutorial() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false);
    }

}
```

and here's my XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.examplecom.FragmentTutorial">

</FrameLayout>
```

my question is...

most tutorials out there try to use this extends statement :

```
public class FragmentTutorial extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
```

in my case, I still need `Fragment` as extends statement. My code won't run if it changed into `YouTubeBaseActivity`.

any idea how to have youtube player inside fragment, specially in tabbed activity like this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FragmentTutorial should extend YouTubePlayerFragment.